# Celery beats add link error signature

Tags: celery, celerybeat

I am looking for solutions to set the celery beats schedule options to a task to include a link_error callback.

My intention is to log exceptions in my scheduled tasks. [Adding a link_error](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks) option seems to be the way forward.

However, I am not sure how I can get the signature of the error task in my settings file.

Here my error handler definition straight from the docs

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def error_handler(self, uuid):
    result = self.app.AsyncResult(uuid)
    logger.error('Task {0} raised exception: {1!r}\n{2!r}'.format(
        uuid, result.result, result.traceback)
    )
```

and my error throwing task

```
@app.task
def failme():    
    raise Exception()
```

Here two things I tried in my schedule but that didn't work

```
'failme-every-10-se': {
    'task': 'ep.tasks.failme',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
    'options': {'link_error': 'ep.tasks.error_handler.s()'}
},
```

and

```
import error_handler

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {    
'error-task-every-5-minutes': {
    'task': 'failme',
    'schedule': timedelta(minutes=5),        
    'options': {'link_error': error_handler.s()}
     },
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're using Django, have you tried with `shared_task` instead of `app.task`?

Comment: In what way would that change the signature of the task definition in the config to get me closer to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Because I did not get a solution to this I resorted to inheriting from a different Task class:

```
class ErrorLoggingTask(Task):
    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        logger.error("Task failed: %s" % einfo)
```

e.g.

```
@shared_task(base=ErrorLoggingTask)
def my_task(arg):
    logger.info("working")
```